# CSS list inline and then on bottom

Tags: css

I need to do some search panel for my site. I try for some hours but nothing... here is my current fiddle where i think i am nearest final..

http://jsfiddle.net/p4z8q/

i need to have

```
<ul class='next_list'>
```

displayed under

```
<ul class='choise_list'>
```

and then next list and next...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p4z8q/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
.next_list{
   clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
ul {
    display:inline;
}
```

css after

```
ol,ul,li { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:hidden` on ul:

```
ul{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4z8q/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.question_list>li{overflow: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the float and use display inline-block. I revised your css as follows:

```
ol,ul,li{
    padding:0;
    margin-right:2px;
    /*background:red;*/
}
.choice_list>li,
.next_list>li {
    background-color: red;
}
.question_list {
    list-style-type:none;
}

#some{background:green;}

.choice_list li {
    /*  float:left; */
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:10%;
}
.next_list li {
    /* float:left; */
   display: inline-block;
   list-style-type:none;
   width:10%;
}
```